# Is the Single ultrafilter topology compact?

Tags: general-topology

It is a special topological space (I think challenging) called Single Ultrafilter topology from the book Counterexamples in Topology.
Let $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ be positive integers and $\mathcal{F}$ be a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and let $X=\mathbb{Z}^{+}\cup\{\mathcal{F}\}$. Take as a basis of open sets all sets of the form $A\cup\{\mathcal{F}\}$ where $A\in\mathcal{F}$, together with the points of $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

It is so clear that the space $X$ is Lindelöf. But is $X$ is compact? or any cover which fails to have a finite subcover? Any help or hint will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not compact.

Choose a cover as follows: pick any element $A$ of $\mathcal F$ such that $\mathbb Z^+\setminus A$ is infinite.

Since $\mathcal F$ is an ultra filter, either the even numbers or the odd numbers would do.
Then
$$\mathscr C =\{\{x\}: x\not\in A\}\cup \{A\cup\{\mathcal F\}\}
$$
is an open cover without finite sub covers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. We can directly say that X is Lindelof since it is countable, right? @Ruy

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: I am so thankful for the help. Thanks again. @Ruy

Comment: You are welcome!  Also, I suggest you read about *accepting answers*  (https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to learn more about this site!

Comment: Surely,  :) @Ruy

Answer (score 1):

One can show even more: the [Single ultrafilter topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000111) is *anticompact*, that is, every compact subset of $X$ is finite.

*Proof*: Let $Y$ be an infinite subset of $X=\mathbb Z^+\cup\{\mathcal F\}$.  We can find two disjoint infinite sets $B,C\subseteq Y\cap\mathbb Z^+$.  Because they are disjoint, they cannot both belong to $\mathcal F$, so suppose $B\notin\mathcal F$. Then by the ultrafilter property, $\mathbb Z^+\setminus B\in\mathcal F$, so $X\setminus B$ is an open nbhd of $\mathcal F$.  Its complement in $X$, namely $B$, is then closed in $X$ and also closed in $Y$.  On the other hand, $B$ is infinite and discrete (as a subspace of $\mathbb Z^+$), so is not compact.  Since $B$ is closed in $Y$, $Y$ is not compact either.